# Best way to search list of elements from javascript array

Tags: javascript

Below is my array I want to search name "gali", "john" and "joe"

```
var dummyArray =  [{
    "fname": "gali",
    "lname": "doe"
}, {
    "fname": "john",
    "lname": "danny"
}, {
    "fname": "joe",
    "lname": "dawns"
}, {
    "fname": "liji",
    "lname": "hawk"
}]
```

one way of doing it is using grep and $.each

```
   var searchcriteria['gali','john','joe'];
   var newArray = [];
   $(searchcriteria).each(function( index ) {
         var item= j$.grep(dummyArray , function(dt) {
         return (dt.fname== searchcriteria[index]);
   });
   newArray.push(item);
});
```

Is there a better apporach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use native JavaScript **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method with **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**

```js
var dummyArray = [{
  "fname": "gali",
  "lname": "doe"
}, {
  "fname": "john",
  "lname": "danny"
}, {
  "fname": "joe",
  "lname": "dawns"
}, {
  "fname": "liji",
  "lname": "hawk"
}]

var searchcriteria = ['gali', 'john', 'joe'];
var newArray = dummyArray.filter(function(ele) {
  return searchcriteria.indexOf(ele.fname) > -1;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

---

It's always better to store search values in an object, since **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** method is pretty slow.

```js
var dummyArray = [{
  "fname": "gali",
  "lname": "doe"
}, {
  "fname": "john",
  "lname": "danny"
}, {
  "fname": "joe",
  "lname": "dawns"
}, {
  "fname": "liji",
  "lname": "hawk"
}]

var searchcriteria = {'gali':true, 'john':true, 'joe':true};
var newArray = dummyArray.filter(function(ele) {
  return searchcriteria[ele.fname];
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: It depends on the number of searchCriteria, I run some test, I add better performance with an array but accessing the value with the name `searchcriteria[ele.fname]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter`

```
var dummyArray =  [{
    "fname": "gali",
    "lname": "doe"
}, {
    "fname": "john",
    "lname": "danny"
}, {
    "fname": "joe",
    "lname": "dawns"
}, {
    "fname": "liji",
    "lname": "hawk"
}];

var searchcriteria = ['gali','john','joe'];
var output = dummyArray.filter(function(x){
 return  searchcriteria.indexOf(x.fname)!=-1
});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
dummyArray.filter(o => searchcriteria.includes(o.fname));
```

```js
var dummyArray = [{
    "fname": "gali",
    "lname": "doe"
}, {
    "fname": "john",
    "lname": "danny"
}, {
    "fname": "joe",
    "lname": "dawns"
}, {
    "fname": "liji",
    "lname": "hawk"
}];

var searchcriteria = ['gali', 'john', 'joe'];

var result = dummyArray.filter(o => searchcriteria.includes(o.fname));
console.log(result);
```

For older browsers not supporting EcmaScript 6, the equivalent code is

```
dummyArray.filter(function (o) {
    return searchcriteria.indexOf(o.fname) !== -1;
});
```